# Failed review audit because flagged to close as opinion-based: was my flag wrong?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Got this question in the "Low quality" queue, and flagged to close because it was primarily opinion-based. Then I received a "You failed" message.

[Java Assertions, in comparison/contrast to Unit Tests and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630791/java-assertions-in-comparison-contrast-to-unit-tests-and-exceptions)

This question looks to me like the archetype of an opinion-based question. If this is not one, what criteria should I use to identify opinion-based questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that some subjective questions are still on-topic.  They are just held to a very rigorous standard.  From the [off-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), opinion-based questions:

> are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean
>   “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be
>   constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Even though the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630791/java-assertions-in-comparison-contrast-to-unit-tests-and-exceptions/30631537#30631537) outright identifies the question as opinion-based, the question (and this answer) meet all the above criteria.  Notice the length and content of the answer.  It's full of explanations and personal coding experience.

Basically, you've just seen one of the rarest questions -- a well-formed subjective question.   The question is **on-topic and the audit is actually accurate**.  Don't feel bad about failing this one though since most of the time, these kinds of questions aren't that well-formed, and the answers they get are really bad.

Answer (score 5):

I would say this is an opinion based question.  This is just one more bad question that got picked as a review audit since it was upvoted and answered.  The answer by [sodik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131829/sodik) even starts of with recognizing it is opinion based:

> This topic is about opinions, so I just add few thoughts that I have about that topic. Those does not cover all the aspects but it can complement others' opinions.